# How did Rocket and teen Groot get to to this location?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Infinity War,

> Thor with Stormbreaker along with Groot and Rocket enters the battle in Wakanda. T'Challa opened the shield for a specific region but the three heroes dropped out of the sky straight into the battle!

How was it possible for Groot and Rocket to do so?

I will surely excuse Thor in this case!

Comment: If you're willing to excuse Thor, then you should be willing to excuse those guys too, since they were riding Thor. Or more specifically, his Bifrost Bridge. Presumably, it's capable of bypassing whatever shielding the Wakandan shield provides.

Comment: @Möoz Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Rocket and Groot were literally *sitting on Thor* when he landed. They took the Bifrost Bridge, just like he did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bifrost uses a powerful, rainbow-like energy drawn from the center of Asgard and can also be summoned through the use of extensive amount of dark magic or enhanced instrument like the Stormbreaker.

As the Bifrost is that powerful and contain that much magic, it acts as a portal directly to the face of the Earth, nothing like a high tech invisible shield can handle.

As Rocket and Groot were sitting on Thor when he landed, we can assume they arrived via the Bifrost along with Thor.

Comment: "drawn from the center of Asgard" It still works even though Asgard got trashed in Thor Ragnorok?

Comment: @user1821961: it sure does. Heimdall summoned it near the start of Infinity War to send Hulk to earth, and Thor can now summon it with his new hammer. I’m guessing it’ll be how they get Tony and Nebula back from Titan in Avengers 4.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm leaning towards Nebula flying them back in the Benatar, which part of the Guardians team flew to Titan to meet Nebula before the battle.

Comment: @Saiboogu: could well be. Thor and co. on earth probably have no idea where Tony actually is.